# Angular google map display in grey color

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

My map is only partially loading the map controls but not rendering the actual map:

my HTML

```
<div class="my-meets-map">
                        <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="map.options">
                            <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
                            </ui-gmap-marker>
                        </ui-gmap-google-map>
                    </div>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0
            },
            zoom: 12
        };
        $scope.options = { scrollwheel: true };
        $scope.marker = {
            id: 1,
            coords: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0
            },
            show: false
        };
```

In CSS:

```
.angular-google-map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            .angular-google-map-container {
                height: 100%;
            }
```

[image: Here Is Screenshot of my Application:]

This Above screenshot is in mobile.
And in desktop or tablet, it displays properly.And If we resize mobile screen in chrome then also map render properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I Added ng-if condition where there is map div.

In My HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 my-meets-map" data-ng-if="render">
     <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="map.options">
         <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
         </ui-gmap-marker>
     </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

In My Controller:

```
$scope.render = false;
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.render = true;
},0);
```

By doing this our HTML DOM render after some time with all value.